# Best Septuagint, Masoretic, and Aramaic texts into one English version?

Tags: hebrew, textual-criticism, septuagint, aramaic, tools-of-biblical-studies

Is there an English version Bible that has the best and oldest translations of the Septuagint and the Masoretic and the Aramaic texts all combined into one translation?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'one text'.  _The Parallel Aligned Hebrew-Aramaic and Greek Texts of Jewish Scripture_ may be of interest.
https://www.logos.com/product/2209/the-parallel-aligned-hebrew-aramaic-and-greek-texts-of-jewish-scripture

Comment: Beverly, I hope this doesn't sound like an advertisement, but check out Gorgias Press.  http://gorgiaspress.com/bookshop/ ...  I used to rely on them for most all of my texts, early Aramaic New Testament versions, (Cureton, etc).  I hope you will find what you are looking for.  But--in one book?  Just give me a few more years .... :)

Comment: @Schuh - Good to know about that Logos product -- but worth noting given OP's interest in *English* translations that Tov's edition is in original languages.

Comment: 'Best translation' is so rarely combined with 'oldest' that I'm going to have to vote to close this as unclear, because you really have not sufficiently specified what criteria you would use to judge these translations as 'best'.

Answer (score 4):

The very short answer is: "no".

- For the Greek Septuagint [see NETS](http://ccat.sas.upenn.edu/nets/edition/);
- for the Aramaic Targumim see the [Aramaic Bible series](http://www.litpress.org/Products/CategoryCenter.aspx?categoryId=S-ABT);
- for the Hebrew Masoretic Text, any [reliable public translation](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1080/2215) will do.

These textual traditions are sufficiently distinct that it would not make sense to have an amalgamated edition (which is what I take it is meant by "all combined into one translation"). One *might* have a "[polyglot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_%28book%29)" edition setting out each tradition in running parallel, but I'm not aware of one that combines these traditions in English translation.

Answer (score 0):

Best Aramaic (Syriac, Targums etc..) here. There's definitely a learning curve to the site.

http://cal.huc.edu/

Click on the left side of the screen "Search the CAL lexical and textual databases" & then click "Text Browse" or "Targum Studies Module"

Also Sefaria has amazing Hebrew (at top) & Targum (at bottom) translations.
https://www.sefaria.org/texts/Tanakh

Targum translations
https://www.sefaria.org/texts/Tanakh/Targum/Targum%20Jonathan